# Sample size calculation of continuous variable in a longitudinal cohort study

Tags: statistical-power

**Context**:
I am writing a grant proposal. In this grant proposal we will make use of secondary data. The point of the sample size calculation is for the board of committee to decide whether or not this proposal has any merit and more importantly if it will result in a publication or not. Otherwise, they can chose a different proposal. Unfortunately, the proposal I wrote previously will not be accepted (for political reasons). This means I have 4 days to write a new one. Normally I would go to a statistician with this question, however, they take atleast one week to respond so it is not possible.

**Population**
Longitudinal prospective cohort study with 2 years of follow-up. Inclusion criteria is patients with spondyloarthritis (SpA) starting a biological (certain medicine).

**Research Question**:
Investigate sex differences in SpA when treated with a biological using the BASDAI as outcome. The BASDAI is a disease activity score and a patient reported outcome (six questions). The sum of score runs from 0 to 100 and is the primary outcome.

**Statistical method**:
I will be using a GLM to investigate the differences in BASDAI (sum of score and composite scores) longitudinally. I am proposing either GLMM or GEE. Final method will be decided in concordance with a statistician.

**Previous literature**:
One [paper](https://ard.bmj.com/content/72/7/1221.long) pooled data from 4 RCT's and found a mean of 62.7 with SD 16.2 for females and 58.6  with SD 16.4 for males at baseline. After 3 months, the mean change in BASDAI was -19.22 for females and -23.41 for male patients. In other words males experienced better improvement compared to females.

**Suggestion for sample size calculation:**
My idea was to look at the difference in the change of female vs. male (-23.41/-19.22 ~ 21.8%). Then use the expected mean at baseline minus the change at 3 months and input this in the following [calculator](https://clincalc.com/stats/samplesize.aspx). Furthermore, I would use an enrollment ratio of 2:1 (as the disease occurs in predominantly males) with an alpha 0.05 and beta of 0.2. Here are the [results](https://ibb.co/HgH54WK) and data input.

I have a strong feeling that this is not the correct way to do this and would love to hear your opinion on this topic.